# composer - Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED "network overload"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I got the following error when I want to update my business network

`Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: received trailing metadata size exceeds limit`

and after checking my system resources I found that only the network was overloaded, may be because of data sent between containers but I do not know what makes it be too high like this.

I am using a virtual machine ubuntu 16.04 and my new update for the business network was

-model

```
/**
 * My commodity trading network
 */
namespace org.example.mynetwork
asset Commodity identified by tradingSymbol {
    o String tradingSymbol
    o String name
    o String description
    o Double value
    --> Trader owner
}
participant Trader identified by traderId {
    o String traderId
    o String firstName
    o String lastName
    o Double balance
    o String password
}
transaction Trade {
    --> Commodity commodity
    --> Trader newOwner
}
```

-transaction

```
/*
*
 * @param {org.example.mynetwork.Trade} trade
 * @transaction
 */
async function tradeCommodity(trade) {
  if(trade.newOwner.balance < trade.commodity.value)
    return;
  trade.commodity.owner.balance = trade.commodity.owner.balance + trade.commodity.value;
  let participantRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.example.mynetwork.Trader');
  await participantRegistry.update(trade.commodity.owner);
  trade.newOwner.balance = trade.newOwner.balance - trade.commodity.value;
  trade.commodity.owner = trade.newOwner;
  let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.example.mynetwork.Commodity');
  await assetRegistry.update(trade.commodity);
  await participantRegistry.update(trade.newOwner);
}
```

I have just tried to create a new network with default implementation and it also failed for the same reason!!!

Answer (score 0):

As observed in [this issue in Composer](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3893) it is likely that you have too many docker containers (and possibly docker images).

If you are happy to "start again" you could try these commands to stop and remove containers, and delete docker images:

`docker stop $(docker ps -q)`

`docker remove $(docker ps -aq)`

`docker rmi $(docker images -q)`

I would suggest `rm -rf ~/.composer` to remove all the 'old' cards, then using the fabric-dev-servers folder use the scripts `downloadFabric.sh`,  `startFabric.sh` and `createPeerAdminCard.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried the following function in my default `trade-network` network - and it works as you intend it to, so very interested to know if it works for you. Also, do you have an existing value for balance for your Trader?

I've created a transaction called `trade2` - so that it also has a separate function name (suffix 2 basically). I am wondering if you've left the function names the same for an existing `trade` transaction in your code and its not calling the right function ??

```
/*
*
 * @param {org.example.mynetwork.Trade2} trade2
 * @transaction
 */

    async function tradeCommodity2(trade2) {
      if(trade2.newOwner.balance < trade2.commodity.value)
        return; // left this for now.

      trade2.commodity.owner.balance = trade2.commodity.owner.balance + trade2.commodity.value;
      console.log(" owner balance after is " + trade2.commodity.owner.balance ) ;
      let participantRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.example.mynetwork.Trader');
      await participantRegistry.update(trade2.commodity.owner);

      trade2.newOwner.balance = trade2.newOwner.balance - trade2.commodity.value;

      trade2.commodity.owner = trade2.newOwner;
      let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.example.mynetwork.Commodity');
      await assetRegistry.update(trade2.commodity);
      await participantRegistry.update(trade2.newOwner);
    }
```

Also you should use `throw` not `return` FYI

eg

```
if(trade2.newOwner.balance < trade2.commodity.value) {
    throw new Error('Insufficient balance');
 }
```